# Checking if all elements in a list are the same in scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, equals, element

Define a recursive procedure 'all-zeroes?' that takes a list of bits and returns #t if and only if the list contains only zeroes. We are representing the bits zero and one by the first and third lower case letters in the word "oil". So far i have

```
(define all-zero?
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (equal? lst '(o))
        #t
        (if (equal? (all-zero? (cons (cdr (lst)) '() )) '(o))
            #t
            #f)
        )
    )
  )
```

but its returning, variable all-zeroes? is not bound. What am i doing wrong and am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

The function in the question is named `all-zero?`, but you're calling it as `all-zeroes?`, that explains the error. There are other more serious mistakes, though:

- You're surrounding `lst` between parentheses, but `lst` is not a function: `(lst)`
- The recursion is not being correctly advanced
- You should use `cond` instead of nesting `if`s

The correct way to implement this function would be to check if any element is *not* zero (returning `#f`) or keep traversing the list until it's empty, taking as convention that an empty list is `#t` for the condition:

```
(define all-zeroes?
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) #t)
          ((not (eq? (car lst) 'o)) #f)
          (else (all-zeroes? (cdr lst))))))
```

The above can be further simplified using boolean connectors:

```
(define all-zeroes?
  (lambda (lst)
    (or (null? lst)
        (and (eq? (car lst) 'o)
             (all-zeroes? (cdr lst))))))
```

Depending on the interpreter in use, you can express the solution more succinctly. For example, in SRFI-1 you can use `every` or in Racket we have `andmap`:

```
(define (all-zeroes? lst)
  (andmap (curry eq? 'o) lst))
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
(all-zeroes? '(o o o))
=> #t
(all-zeroes? '(o o l))
=> #f
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for 'all zeros' in a list.  If the first element of the list is not a zero then you are done with a false answer; if the first element is a zero, then continue on.  When the list is empty then it had all zeros.  This is expressed naturally using recursion, as such:

```
(define (all-zero? list)
  (or (null? list)                     ; #t if list is empty
      (and (eq? 'o (car list))         ; head is zero … 
           (all-zero? (cdr list)))))   ; … continue with rest.
```

Your code had a number of errors and style slip-ups:

1. `(cdr (lst))` ends up making a function call to `lst` but `lst` is not a function
2. boolean functions, like `equal?` return #t/#f; no need to add them to your code
3. stylistically 'hanging parens' (parens on a line by themselves) are to be avoided.
4. your comparison with `equal?` should be based on the first element of `lst`